# Как клонировать GIT репозиторий и развернуть локально в Docker

Tags: docker

Как клонировать файлы из репозитория  и развернуть сайт локально через контейнер Docker.
Кнопка Switch to не работает, так как используется Windows 10 Домашняя.
Клонировать файлы получилось, но как его содержимое запустить в Docker?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Исправлено, если что-то надо добавить, напишите чего именно не хватает

Comment: Возможно это вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67023441/deploy-docker-container-with-compose-github-actions

Answer (score 1):

В домашней версии вы никак не установите докер.

Системные требования для установки докера на ОС Windows:

1. 64 битная версия не ниже Pro
2. Аппаратная поддержка виртуализации (включается в BIOS)

Поставьте linux второй системой.